# ImageView Problemas com o tamanho original

Tags: imageview, bitmap

O `ImageView` por padrão vem com a resolução que ronda `90x120`, deste modo a perda de qualidade é notória quando usando o `Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)bundle.get("data");`

Existe outra forma de pegar a imagem sem ser por arquivo e pelo proprio `imageView` com uma qualidade razoável?